# "Cannot find build.xml" error building Android SDK sample

Tags: android, ant

The log is:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> /Users/xxx/sample/build.xml:114: Cannot find /Users/xxx/Library/Android/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml imported from /Users/xxx/sample/build.xml

I can confirm that sdkdir is right.

I found there is not an ant directory in `/Users/xxx/Library/Android/Library/Android/sdk/tools/`.

I found someone saying it is automatically generated. How can I make this build.xml in tools/ant? I use a Mac.

Comment: just download the version of tools below 26.0

Comment: Download the 25.2.5, not the 25.3 it will not work.

Answer (score 11):

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip

Download archive and replace tools folder of your android sdk

Answer (score 2):

You have to install an old Android Sdk version. The latest ones doesn't have `tools\ant` folder.

You can download older version [here](http://android-sdk-tools.en.lo4d.com/download/mirror-ex1). Download archive and replace `tools` folder of your sdk.